# md-tabs not showing scroll or pagination

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I have recently upgraded my angularjs material version from 1.0.9 to 1.1.10. After the change my scroll bars have stopped showing up in the sides of my tab menu panels when there is an overflow. This used to work fine earlier. 
Now I only see the following in the Devtools, for some reason the this flag is not becoming true for the pagination to work. Please let me know what could be the issue here.

```
<!-- ngIf: $mdTabsCtrl.shouldPaginate -->
```

This is the code that I have.

```
<div class="mainContentWrapper md-whiteframe-2dp" id="mainContentWrapper" style="overflow:auto;">
            <div class="tab-panel">
                <md-content class="md-padding">
                    <md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex" md-border-bottom md-autoselect>
                        <md-tab>
                            <img class="dashboard" width="20" src="../../images/dashboard-icon1.png" />
                            <md-tooltip md-direction="right" ng-click="backToDashboard()">
                                Dashboard
                            </md-tooltip>
                        </md-tab>
                        <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
                                ng-disabled="tab.disabled"
                                title="{{tab.desc}}" ng-if="$index>0">
                            {{tab.title}}
                            <md-tooltip>
                                {{tab.desc}}
                            </md-tooltip>
                        </md-tab>
                    </md-tabs>
                </md-content>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There has been a change in implementation from 1.0.9 to 1.1.10. in the new version its using MutationObserver to detect any change to decide if it needs to show pagination.

```
var mutationCallback = function() {
        ctrl.updatePagination();
        ctrl.updateInkBarStyles();
      };

      if('MutationObserver' in $window) {
        var config = {
          childList: true,
          subtree: true,
          // Per https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1138368, browsers will not fire
          // the childList mutation, once a <span> element's innerText changes.
          // The characterData of the <span> element will change.
          characterData: true
        };

        observer = new MutationObserver(mutationCallback);
        observer.observe(element[0], config);
        disconnect = observer.disconnect.bind(observer);
      } else {
        var debounced = $mdUtil.debounce(mutationCallback, 15, null, false);

        element.on('DOMSubtreeModified', debounced);
        disconnect = element.off.bind(element, 'DOMSubtreeModified', debounced);
      }
```

Previously it was using only $mdUtil.debounce(mutationCallback, 100) which means it was updating the flags every 100ms. for some reason when I resize my window the mutation is not triggered. So I had to manually mutate the contents of the tab on resizing the tabs. I dont like this fix. Am I missing something?